# Custom binding no longer working in KnockoutJS 3.0

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

All of the sudden, the following code no longer works when targeting KnockoutJS 3.0.  How can I work around this?

JavaScript:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.limitCharacters = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel)
    {
       element.value = element.value.substr(0, valueAccessor());
       allBindingsAccessor().value(element.value.substr(0, valueAccessor()));
    }
};
```

HTML:

```
<textarea data-bind="value: comment, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', limitCharacters: 20"></textarea>
```

See fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/ReQrz/1/

Comment: Maybe problem in your browser? In my FF 25.0.1 and GC 31.0 it works perfect.

Comment: Sometimes we put custom binding handlers in separate scripts. Consider running them when document is ready. Just try enclosing it with $(function(){}), if using jQuery

Comment: Alexander - it's limiting the text and stopping at the max?

Comment: The fiddle is the non-3.0 "working" version

Answer (score 6):

In KO 3.0 the bindings are Independent and ordered. You can read more about this [here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2013/07/09/knockout-v2-3-0-released-v3-0-0-beta-available/), and this should be considered a "breaking change", from the above linked example:

> v2.x’s behavior about dependencies between bindings (described in the
>   section about “Independent and ordered bindings” above), is an
>   **undocumented internal implementation detail** so hopefully you aren’t
>   relying on it. But if you are relying on that then **obviously you will
>   see a change of behavior because bindings are independent in v3 by
>   design.** You’ll need to stop relying on cross-binding dependencies,
>   which by the way will make your code much cleaner and easier to
>   understand.

So you binding is not working anymore because it assumed that when your `comment` property is changed it fires also your `limitCharacters` binging altough your `limitCharacters` binding has nothing to do with the `comment` property.

One possible solution for fixing this that you need to explicitly declare a dependency on the `value` binding in your `update` handler by acessing its value with `allBindingsAccessor().value();`:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.limitCharacters = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel)
    {
       var val = allBindingsAccessor().value();       
       allBindingsAccessor().value(val.substr(0, valueAccessor()));
    }
};
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s5Wgq/).

Comment: +2; I got my friend to +1 it as well, this was so timely and useful. :)

Answer (score 1):

nemesv is completely right.

His modification is short and easy to read. One drawback of that though is the observable is called twice when in exceeds the limit.

If you don't want that, a solution is to create a custom value binder which derives from the original.

```
(function() {
    var limitValueBindingHandler = {};

    var valueBindingHandler = ko.bindingHandlers.value;
    for(var attr in valueBindingHandler) {
        if (valueBindingHandler.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
            limitValueBindingHandler[attr] = valueBindingHandler[attr];
        }
    }

    limitValueBindingHandler.init = function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        var limitCharacters = allBindings.get("limitCharacters");

        element.addEventListener("keydown", function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                //this is called after the element's value is updated
                //but before value binding event handler
                element.value = element.value.substr(0, limitCharacters);
            }, 0);
        }, false);

        valueBindingHandler.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindings);
    }

    ko.bindingHandlers['limitValue'] = limitValueBindingHandler;
})();
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/DAFN6/